# Get properties from second (Right) joined entity with Group by

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

please I'm working on a `ASP.NET MVC` project with `Entity Framework`.
I try to write a `Linq` Query that give me some data, this Query will join two entities and grouping by data, so the issue is when I try to get the properties of second joined entity I don't see them in `Intellisense`, I need these properties to select them.

**What I try :**

```
var R = (from N in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.NT_CTR join S in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.STGs on N.STG_nt equals S.CD_STG where N.CTR_nt==CTR group N by N.STG_nt into G select new NT_CTR_Anal { /*Here where I want to select some properties from second entity*/ } )
```

So please any help about this issue ?

Comment: So the problem is how to select certain properties?

Comment: I never use this query-type syntax, but what type are you getting in that block?

Comment: @insane_developer What block talking about ? what are you mean ?

Comment: @ADSMB I meant whether you can access S, like the answer suggests, or else what are you able to access from inside `select new NT_CTR_Anal { /*Here where I want to select some properties from second entity*/ }.

Comment: Thanks, I want like this `select new NT_CTR_Anal {   Prop1=S.S_property_1,Prop2=S.S_property_2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at tis fragment:

```
group N by N.STG_nt into G
```

The part between `by` and `into` is the key(s), and similar to SQL there you have access to all aliases (variables) from `from` and `join` clauses. The name after `into` is LINQ specific and represents the alias (variable) for accessing the `GroupBy` result. But what is between `group` and 'by'? There is no SQL equivalent.

Well, the result of `GroupBy` is of type `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, which has property `TKey Key` and also is `IEnumerable<TElement>`. The `TKey` is comong from the expression between `by` and `into`, while `TElement` (which is what you can access through `into` variable is coming from the expression between `group` and `by`.

In your sample you've put `N` there, that`s why you have access only to its properties.

In order to have access to other properties, you would use the typical LINQ construct for "composite" things, which is anonymous type projection, e.g.

```cs
var R = (
    from N in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.NT_CTR
    join S in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.STGs on N.STG_nt equals S.CD_STG
    where N.CTR_nt == CTR
    group new { N, S } by N.STG_nt into G
    select new NT_CTR_Anal
    {
        G.Key, // N.STG_nt
        SomeNPropSum = G.Sum(e => e.N.SomeNProp),
        SomeSPropSum = G.Sum(e => e.S.SomeSProp),
    };
```

As you can see, now you have access to both `N` and `S` properties inside grouping aggregate methods.

Comment: Massive thanks bro, you are a life saver. But I have last question when I applied `(e => e.N.SomeNProp)` on a `string` property   I got an error : **cannot implicitly convert type string to long**, Please do you have any help ?

Comment: What aggregate method? I think strings support only `Min` and `Max`.

Comment: You are a life saver, Massive thanks bro, you taugh me something new, thanks again